# Pattern to communicate with a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, synchronization, nonblocking

I have a class `OuterClass` that contains a `List` and there is a thread `ListWorker` that is started in `OuterClass` that is adding some elements to the list. Based on a function call to `OuterClass` , it should be able to inform the thread to delete elements. What is the best practise? The intention is not to have a blocking data structure (no synchronization) and therefore having a single thread work on List.

```
Class OuterClass {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListWorker worker = new ListWorker(list);

    deleteLastElement() {
        worker.setDeleteLastElement(true);
    }
}
```

The worker

```
ListWorker implements Runnable {

private List<String> list;
private volatile boolean deleteLastElement;

public void setDeleteLastElement(boolean deleteLastElement) {
    this.deleteLastElement = deleteLastElement; 
}

public ListWorker(List<String> list) {
   this.list = list;
}

public void run() {
while(true) {
    //add random elements

    if(deleteLastElement) {
     //delete last element
     //set the boolean now to false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can add a Commandobject to a "workqueue" of the wokerThread? Just setting a Boolean seems really not stable to me.

Comment: @Fildor can you elaborate on CommandObject?

Comment: Think of it as a pile of files on a worker's desk. People come and put their Tasks on top of the pile. The worker takes the downmost and works on it ... People (=other threads) will not be blocked, but they may have to wait for their changerequests to become effective. Is it this that you want? You could even use a blocking queue, then you thread doesn't even need spin-waits ...

Comment: @Fildor exactly. That is what I want. I have a buffer which all the threads interact with and that is thread-safe and lock-free. I just have one thread work on processing these things. That is the worker thread. Does the command object work for this use case?

Comment: Sure. I don't have time to write a complete answer. If there is no answer by tomorrow, I'll write something up.

Comment: @Fildor and what is the best way to stop the thread after the instance that has started this thread had died?

Comment: Make the run method exit.

Comment: @Fildor Can you do a small example of Command Objects? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested and may need some additional Exception handling but that's roughly it:

```
ListWorker implements Runnable {

    private interface Command{
        void execute();
    }

private List<String> list;
private BlockingQueue<ListWorker.Command> work; // give it a Blocking Queue impl.
private volatile boolean bAddRandomElements;


public synchronized void deleteLastElement() {
     work.add( new Command(){
            @Override
            public void execute(){ /* delete Last Element of the list */ }
        } ); 
}

public synchronized void startAddingRandom() {
     work.add( new Command(){
            @Override
            public void execute(){ /* set switch bAddRandomElements */ }
        } ); 
}

public synchronized void stopAddingRandom() {
     work.add( new Command(){
            @Override
            public void execute(){ /* reset switch bAddRandomElements */ }
        } ); 
}

public synchronized void terminate() {
     work.add( new Command(){
            @Override
            public void execute(){ /* interrupt thread */ }
        } ); 
}


public ListWorker(List<String> list) {
   this.list = list;
}

public void run() {
    while(!Thread.interrupted()) {
       Command c = null;
       if( bAddRandomElements ){ 
           /* add random, assuming you add one random entry per iteration ... */
           c = work.poll( /*maybe specify timeout*/ ); // No command - just go on with it! We'll block in next iteration if bAddRandomElements is reset.
       }else{
           c = work.take(); // blocks until there is a command in queue.
       }

       if ( null != c ) c.execute();

    }
}
```

Comment: this is amazing. Now the commands can be executed in the order they are called and will be not missed if multiple threads try setting the values. Thanks!